# Nested route's template not getting rendered in EmberJS app

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, routes, url-routing

I'm setting up a testing Ember app that currently looks like this:

```
App = window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('subscriptions', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('media', { path: '/:photo_id' });
  });
});

App.SubscriptionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Subscription.findAll();
  }
});

App.SubscriptionsMediaRoute = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Subscription.find(params.photo_id);   
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { photo_id: model.photo_id };
  }
});

App.Subscription = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Subscription.reopenClass({
  findAll: function(id) {
    var subs = Ember.A([
      App.Subscription.create({ id: 1, photo_id: 221, name: "Test 1" }),
      App.Subscription.create({ id: 2, photo_id: 222, name: "Test 2" }),
      App.Subscription.create({ id: 3, photo_id: 223, name: "Test 3" })
    ]);  

    return subs; 
  }
});
```

The idea is to display a list of subscriptions and each one will eventually link to some media (images) to show when visiting the correct route, I'm displaying the list of subscriptions like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="subscriptions">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="list-group">
        {{#each subscription in controller}}
          {{#linkTo 'subscriptions.media' subscription classNames="list-group-item"}}
            {{subscription.name}}
          {{/linkTo}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="subscriptions/media">
    Display photos here -- NOT RENDERING --
</script>
```

It all looks fine but for some reason my `subscriptions/media` template is not showing up on the subscriptions outlet when I click the links, here's a jsbin for reference: http://jsbin.com/ubumag/3/edit

Any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App.SubscriptionsMediaRoute` is not necessary, this is default behaviour that ember does already automatically given your router map, so remove it or comment it out and everything will work just fine.

See [here](http://jsbin.com/ubumag/5/edit) your working jsbin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks however the problem is that I need the `photo_id` value in my url to fetch the photos in the `subscriptions.media` route later on not the `id` that's why I'm using the `serialize` function, but considering it works fine without that code then I must be implementing it wrong